# delphi sorting descending

Tags: delphi, sorting

I’m trying to sort the records (in descending order ) and display the data in  grid which is connected through datasource to the dataset Vw_EmpVacations
Here is the code, please tell me what I did wrong
By the way,  the view is sorted descending according to start_date when I execute it in the database

```
Vw_EmpVacations.Active:=false;
Vw_EmpVacations.SQL.Text:='select * from Vw_EmpVacations where Branch_ID=:x and emp_id=:y and vac_id=:z order by Start_Date  Desc ';
Vw_EmpVacations.Parameters[0].Value:=branch_ID;
Vw_EmpVacations.Parameters[1].Value:=emp_Id;
Vw_EmpVacations.Parameters[2].Value:=Vac_ID;
Vw_EmpVacations.Active:=true;
```

thank you

Comment: So you want to sort rows in descending order which are already sorted in descending order? I am sorry, I think you need to work a little bit more on your question. Format code properly, tell us what database components you are using, dbGo, dbExpress, IBO, FIBPlus...?

Comment: data is sorted in the view, but when I try to displyed it in the grid it is not sorted anymore. I'm using ADOquery, XDBgrid, XQRgrid

Comment: Try to first connect it to standard Delphi TDBGrid, is it sorted in this component?

Comment: I tried it but still not sorted... I noticed somethig strange, while I was checking the view (Im using sql Server 2005) when i click view--> design and the run it the data is sored, but if I click view--> open view I see the data is not sorted... how and why??

Comment: Try your Base + Table + Query with other ADO Delphi code like  http://sourceforge.net/projects/axbase/ , then if all is OK, compare your code and the working code !

Comment: Order by statements in [views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) is used only to determine what rows should be returned when using select top. To be certain of a sort order you always have to provide an order by in the query using the view. By the looks of it, you have done that so I can see nothing in your code here that should be done differently. Your error is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to help you despite the fact that you are very sparse in details about your problem;-)

Please create a new VCL Forms Application - Delphi For Win32 project.
Then, replace the source of project with this code:

```
program SortTest;

uses
  Forms, ADODB, DB, DBGrids;

var
  qrySortTest: TADOQuery;
  conSQL2005: TADOConnection;
  dsSortTest: TDataSource;
  grdTest: TDBGrid;
  MainForm: TForm;
begin

  Application.Initialize;

  conSQL2005 := TADOConnection.Create(Application);
  with conSQL2005 do
  begin
    Name := 'conSQL2005';
    //Do not forget to change the connection string
    ConnectionString :=
      'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security In' +
      'fo=False;Data Source=WODZU-LAPTOP\SQL2005S';
    LoginPrompt := False;
    Provider := 'SQLOLEDB.1';
    Connected := True;
  end;

  qrySortTest := TADOQuery.Create(Application);
  with qrySortTest do
  begin
    Name := 'qrySortTest';
    Connection := conSQL2005;
    CursorType := ctStatic;
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('SELECT '#39'Kowalsky'#39' as Surname, 25 as Age');
    SQL.Add('UNION');
    SQL.Add('SELECT '#39'Smith'#39', 38');
    SQL.Add('UNION');
    SQL.Add('SELECT '#39'Jensen'#39', 11');
    SQL.Add('UNION');
    SQL.Add('SELECT '#39'Doe'#39', 26');
    SQL.Add('UNION');
    SQL.Add('SELECT '#39'Clarke'#39', 45');
    SQL.Add('ORDER BY AGE DESC');
    Active := True;
  end;

  dsSortTest := TDataSource.Create(Application);
  with dsSortTest do
  begin
    Name := 'dsSortTest';
    DataSet := qrySortTest;
  end;

  MainForm := TForm.Create(Application);
  MainForm.Position := poScreenCenter;

  grdTest := TDBGrid.Create(Application);

  with grdTest do
  begin
    Name := 'grdTest';
    Parent := MainForm;
    Left := 8;
    Top := 8;
    Width := 320;
    Height := 120;
    DataSource := dsSortTest;
    TabOrder := 0;
  end;


  MainForm.ShowModal;

  Application.Run;
end.
```

Remember to put **correct connection string** to your SQL Server, otherwise it will not work.
Run the test, does it show you rows sorted by `Age` column in descending order? If yes, then this is the place for you to start.

Replace the qrySortTest.SQL with your **parameterless** query and check if it works. If not, then the problem lies in your query not in the component setup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using Delphi6 and I tried New-> Others -> but there isn't VCL Form application. what to do ?

Comment: You just need to create a new VCL Project, I do not remember the exact name of that option in Delphi 6. I've created the project file for you, download it from here: http://www.speedyshare.com/file/xShfp/SortTest.dpr

Comment: Thank you so much, very professional  way of testing and thank you for building the project